# C'è una differenza semantica tra "un X" e "... come X"?

Tags: meaning

> Londra è una città grande.

> Londra è grande come città.

**C'è una differenza in significato tra queste frasi o la differenza è soltanto stilistica?**

Per me l'espressione "come città" è sempre stata un errore linguistico poiché è ridondante aggiungere che Londra è una città. Nonostante, oggi ho capito che forse è un modo di fuga nelle situazioni dove vogliamo precisare la categoria, ma non abbiamo messo l'articolo nel momento giusto.

Answer (score 5):

*Londra è grande come città* non è  un errore, ne' penso  sia quello che chiami 'un modo di fuga', con cui penso che intendi un modo per rimediare,  quando si è sbagliato a collocare l'articolo.

Aggiungere *come città* può essere senz'altro ridondante, ma può essere una scelta di stile, non è certo la prima volta che si usa un [**pleonasmo**](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pleonasmo/), è una figura retorica.

Inoltre, dire semplicemente *Londra è grande*, può anche risultare ambiguo in alcuni contesti, poiché *grande* potrebbe anche significare ad esempio *molto interessante, molto stimolante, magnifica* e simili.

Mentre aggiungendo *come città* si chiarisce che ci si riferisce alle dimensioni, del territorio o della popolazione, direi più all'estensione del territorio.

Riguardo alla tua domanda:

> > Londra è una città grande.
>
> > Londra è grande come città.
>
> **C'è una differenza in significato tra queste frasi o la differenza è soltanto stilistica?**

No, non riesco a vedere differenze di significato.